# I keep getting “Expected Identifer or “(“, what does this mean and how do I fix it?

Tags: c++, xcode

I keep getting an “expected identifier or ‘(‘ error message

Here is my code:

```
int i = 0;
while( i++ < 5)
{
   if (i == 2)
   {
       continue;
   }
   printf(“%d”, i);
}
```

I tried taking out spaces but the build keeps failing.

Comment: Problem with quotation marks. `printf(%d”, i);` should be `printf("%d", i);`. Note that C++ uses `"` not `”`, but word processors may 'disrupt' your code by converting regular quotes to "smart quotes"

Comment: I made a mistake while typing the code on here. I do have quotations on both sides but thanks for the tip.

Comment: I suspect you are using Microsoft Word or similar word processor to do your code instead of an IDE.  That why you're code has the unicode `“%d”` instead of `"%d"`  Literally use the quote char on the keyboard. Don't use word processing software or email editors to code.

Comment: Is there a `main` function anywhere in your code that you aren't showing us?

Answer (score 2):

`”` is not the same character as `"`. For programming in C++ you *must* use the latter one.

If you are coding in an IDE or code editor, the character should map correctly directly from your keyboard (at least keyboard layouts/languages I know all have a key for this character).

However, if you are typing your code in a general purpose text editor or word processor, it might modify the character, e.g. to match the quotation marks used in your native written language. Use a proper IDE in that case.